# How does :only work in this ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just started to learn ruby today and I have a question regarding the following code.
I wonder how exactly does ":only =>:show" affect the code here. I would assume that if we don't have ":only =>:show", then the code will process authenticate directly. But what exactly does ":only =>:show" do? Thanks!

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate, :only =>:show

  def index
    @people = ["luke-skywalker", "darth-vader"]
  end

  def show
    @person = params[:id]
  end

  private

  def authenticate
    if params[:id] == "darth-vader"
      redirect_to people_url, :notice => "The page is restricted."
      #this is called the flash message
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a [hash](http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash) argument to the `before_filter` method (see the [filters docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)) that indicated the filter method should only run before the "show" method.

`:only` is a hash key, `:show` is a symbol that maps to the `show` controller method.

Answer (score 1):

Before filter is a callback saying to call this method before processing the actual action you called. :only => :show tells the callback to only do that for the show action. If you take it out, the method is called before all actions

Answer (score 0):

In ROR, filters are functions or procs that are evaluated before the actions.
If you don't say otherwise, the filter is evaluated before every action. 
You can pass :only and :except for specify which action may or may not be filtered.

Answer (score 0):

The program is passing a literal `Hash` object in the second argument to the method `before_filter`.

When a `Hash` literal is the last parameter to a method, Ruby allows the `{` and `}` to be dropped.

This is particularly helpful in poetry mode, as the `{` would otherwise appear to be starting a block.  Commas are interpreted as continuing the `Hash` literal rather than as continuing the argument list.

Try this and see:

```
def f x
  p x
end
f :a => :b, :c => :d
f({:a => :b, :c => :d})
```